# how to install devise member in rails 4.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

how to generate [devise](/questions/tagged/devise) member in [rails](/questions/tagged/rails) 4.0.2:

```
anubhav@ubuntu:~/rail$ rails generate devise:model
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:44:in `resolve_string_connection': development database is not configured (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:30:in `spec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:39:in `establish_connection'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:176:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:322:in `<module:ActiveRecord>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise/orm/active_record.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /home/anubhav/rail/config/initializers/devise.rb:22:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.2/lib/devise.rb:288:in `setup'
from /home/anubhav/rail/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /home/anubhav/rail/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:229:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:44:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this line might be the clue

"development database is not configured"

Check the content of config/database.yml

and Gemfile to ensure you are using a database adapter that is installed. If you are using mysql for example ensure you have:

config/database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: yourDbName
  username: yourSQLUser
  password: passwordHere
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 3306
```

Gemfile

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

and mysql installed on the system also

If you were trying to run in production maybe you need to run

```
 rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production
```

or postfix whatever command with RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: and also `rails generate devise MODE`L : you have to substitute MODEL with the name of YOUR model, that should be Member if i understood.

Comment: Yep that's true too. should be "rails g devise User" or whatever you want the model to be as above. Good spot

Answer (score 1):

`anubhav@ubuntu:~/rail$ rails generate devise MODEL`  ,   eg: `rails generate devise User` to generate a User model